# What do I do if I'm in the restroom and the Azaan starts?

Tags: halal-haram, adhan

I want to know if I'm in the restroom and the azaan starts, like usual do I respond to the azaan to just hear it?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure If there's a specific Hadith or saying of an Islamic scholar about this, but in some matters, in Islam, we should use our common sense.

We know that in the restroom where there's a toilet we are not allowed to say the name of Allah in Islam, thus I believe, that after we have done the business and are out of the place then we answer the adhan and It should still be correct since adhan is wajib (obligatory) but there is no condition that It should be answered immediately.

Though a better thing to do would be to just give the answer before going to the restroom, It's only like 30 seconds mostly, unless you can't handle it.